# Flutter local notifications

Tags: flutter

I' m using Flutter local notification for my app with repeatInterval, it's working fine but i want notifications to be different from one to another, cause with this code i get the same string from list over and over again. How can i edit the code to get another string when user get a notification?

```
Future<void> showNotification(int id, String title, String body) async {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.periodicallyShow(
      id,
      title,
      body,
      RepeatInterval
          .everyMinute, 
      const NotificationDetails(
        // Android details
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails('main_channel', 'Main Channel',
            channelDescription: "ashwin",
            importance: Importance.max,
            priority: Priority.max),
        // iOS details
        iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails(
          sound: 'default.wav',
          presentAlert: true,
          presentBadge: true,
          presentSound: true,
        ),
      ),
      androidAllowWhileIdle:
          true, // To show notification even when the app is closed
    );
  }
```

Here is the code from another class NotificationService and i called it here:

```
 onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        showToast();
                        NotificationService().showNotification(
                          1,
                          '$randomNames${widget.userPost}',
                          randomName!,
                        );
                      });
                    },
```

The problem it s only updating when i press the button again, i want to be updated every time when the user get a notification. Anybody know how to do that?

```
    String? randomName;
    final random = new Random();
    randomName = names[random.nextInt(names.length)];
```

This is where i randomized the list called names, this code and the one from above are from a diferent screen class called IntroPage

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set different notif, which means you need the the system to execute the function. but since its repeated notif, and the message was static, consider to use `Workmanger`.

https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager

with this ,you can execute your function to generate random text as a notification.

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point') 
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) {
   //you function here to generete random String
  // then show local notificaton
    
   showNotification(); // call local notificaiton

    return Future.value(true);
  });
}

void main() {
  Workmanager().initialize(
    callbackDispatcher, // The top level function, aka callbackDispatcher
    isInDebugMode: true // If enabled it will post a notification whenever the task is running. Handy for debugging tasks
  );
  Workmanager().registerPeriodicTask("task-identifier", "simpleTask");
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: pmatatias i get an error when i put the workmanger code inside the void main

Comment: you need to read documentation for the setup